# I want to set roles by Chat | Discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
MuteUser = message.mentions.members.first();
MuteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get("x")
```

I want to change my role like using ".rolemute @Muted"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply define the muted role:

```js
var mutedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get("x")
```

Then if you ever want to change by a message:

```js
var prefix = '.';
if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + 'rolemute') { //when the command "rolemute" is said...
    let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g); //split the message.
    if (!args[1]) return message.channel.send('You have not mentioned a new muted role.'); //if user did not mention a new role return a message.
    mutedRole = message.mentions.roles.first() || message.guild.roles.cache.get(args[1]); //define the new role.
    if (!mutedRole) return message.channel.send('I could not find the role you have specified.'); //If the role does not exist in the guild.
    message.channel.send(`Your muted role is now set to ${mutedRole}.`); //If the new muted role was successful.
```

Comment: thanks i never tried args for this i have tried message.mentions.roles.first(); Thanks Again!

Comment: [my code](https://sourceb.in/FGuI6h0oyu) Supplied roles is not a Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes` – i have this error now

Comment: Change `let MutedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get("'" + MuteRole + "'");` to `let MutedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get(MuteRole);`.

Answer (score 0):

`message.mentions` returns an instance of the [`MessageMentions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions) class. Along with that having `members` and `users` properties, it also has `channels`, and fortunately, `roles`!

```js
const MuteRole = message.mentions.roles.first();
```

Comment: Now I have this
`
Supplied roles is not a Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes`

Comment: I'm only guessing, as I can't see your full code, but either you didn't mention a `MuteRole` (which you should handle: `if (!MuteRule) return message.channel.send('Error Message')`) or you modified it in some way.

Comment: https://sourceb.in/FGuI6h0oyu here is my command

Comment: ....you didn't use `message.mentions.roles.first()`

Comment: it dont matter when I use args or mentions it gives type error.

Comment: Could you show me the code where you use `message.mentions.users.first()`?